# How to change formatting rules for X++ in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-ax7

Visual Studio has the nice feature to autoformat your code.

Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document
Or you can use the according shortcut.

I would like to change some of the **formatting settings** for my language, which is X++ for Dynamics AX.

When I open the options menu (Tools -> Options), I see that there a lot of formatting options for C#, C++, HTML ... but none for X++ (except the usual use tab or whitespace options for intendation).

So my questions are:

1. What settings is Visual Studio using at the moment when I click
   Format Document? It is definitly doing some things with the brace
   style and not only changing intendation.
2. How can I change these settings - or how can I create my own set of formatting rules?

Any input is appreciated.